# Provide solution for "inline evaluation error" in jmeter(error code 500)

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

Response code:500
Response message:Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``WDS.log.error('xyz') WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() WDS.log.error('xyz1') WDS.br . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: "y" (121), after : "'x": 
in

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) language and your code isn't valid Beanshell code, Beanshell Strings (as well as Java [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)) are supposed to be surrounded by double quotation marks `"`  and also don't forget about semicolons `;` at statement ends

So you need to change this:

```
WDS.log.error('xyz')
```

to this:

```
WDS.log.error("xyz");
```

or just switch to `groovy`, your code would be valid groovy code, moreover [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead).